# Double posting of question

Tags: bug

<s>The last time I checked, there was a forty-minute cooldown to asking questions</s>(see first comment). However, I noticed that one user has posted the exact same question twice at approx. the same time.
[image]

Is this a bug in the system or have things changed?

[User Profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/908782/requiemman)

[First question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539054/where-am-i-gonig-wrong-while-trying-to-figure-out-the-sum-of-the-finite-series)

[Second question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539055/where-am-i-gonig-wrong-while-trying-to-figure-out-the-sum-of-the-finite-series)

Comment: I have tested it out and it appears that I can post two questions within 40 minutes of each other(I have deleted both questions since they are invalid). I will leave this up just in case, however.

Comment: Since the times for both questions appears to be the same, this issue may be due to what is described in the network Meta post [Sometimes, submitting a question can lead to two identical copies of the same question posted at the same time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346338/562482).

Comment: According to "[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)", the 40-minute limit is only for users below 125 reputation points. (That should explain why you were allowed to post two questions close after each other.)